# Disable outside click dialog box angular material

Tags: angular

Ive added code to disable the outside click closing of the dialog box. This isnt working, can anybody tell me where am i wrong here? Here is code example below is used disableClose as the boolean variable to disable the closing of the dialog box.

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TempDialog, { disableClose: true }) {
      data: { person: " ", place: "", thing: this.thing }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      dialogRef.disableClose = true;
}
```

Comment: That code looks very interesting, does it really compile? Try pasting only this line inside your `openDialog` method. `const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TempDialog, { disableClose: true, data: { person: " ", place: "", thing: this.thing }});`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the API: 
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api.

`disableClose` is part of `MatDialogConfig` that should be passed to dialog when opening it. This guide has a good example: 
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/